# NSUserNotification not working with wx.app.MainLoop() method

Tags: python, wxpython, pyobjc

Here is simple code that uses PyObjC interface to show the desktop notification. When I call notify method without wx.app.MainLoop() it works fine but with wx.app.MainLoop() it not.

```
import Foundation, objc

NSUserNotification = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotification')
NSUserNotificationCenter = objc.lookUpClass('NSUserNotificationCenter')

def notify(title, subtitle, info_text, delay=0, sound=False, userInfo={}):

  notification = NSUserNotification.alloc().init()
  notification.setTitle_(title)
  notification.setSubtitle_(subtitle)
  notification.setInformativeText_(info_text)
  notification.setUserInfo_(userInfo)
  if sound:
    notification.setSoundName_("NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName")

  notification.setDeliveryDate_(Foundation.NSDate.dateWithTimeInterval_sinceDate_(delay, Foundation.NSDate.date()))
  NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().scheduleNotification_(notification)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    notify("Notify Tittle", "Notify Subtitle", "Notify body")
    app.MainLoop()    # commenting this line shows the desktop notification
```